# C# Console application read/writes on standard IO doesn't works

Tags: c#

Have C# Console application which read/writes on standard input and output.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Console application");

        while(true)
        {
            int input = Console.Read();

            Console.WriteLine(input.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I have other native application which launch above console application and read/writes with help of pipe communication.
C# console application writes are read successfully in external application and also initial writes from external application works fine and then it loops to read from the C# console application.
After that writes from external application on the pipe doesn't work.

Absurd thing is problem is happening on some of the operating system and few it is working fine.

C# Console application compile with .NET Framework 4 / Client Profile.

Comment: Not really enough details here.  Can you add the code for your external application as well?  We need to see how the problem can be fully reproduced.

Comment: @Mike Native application is simple application which does pipe communication with the C# console application.
Strange thing is it works on few operating systems and on few the write on pipe from external application does't recognized by console application. .Net Framework version will affect such behavior.

Comment: @update The issue doesn't come when i use .NET 3.5 runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Known issue from MS :
http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2675468

Please check the KB for more details along with sample provided.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput()));
    while (Console.In.Peek() != -1)
    {
        string input = Console.In.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }
}
```

Does it work that way?

EDIT: I have updated my answer.

Sample usage/output:

```
dir /B | ConsoleApplication1.exe
```

produces:

```
ConsoleApplication1.exe
ConsoleApplication1.exe.config
ConsoleApplication1.pdb
ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe.config
ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe.manifest
```

When I try your original code, it ends up spamming -1 constantly.
You can also try:

```
while (true)
{
    int input = Console.Read();
    if (input != -1) { // -1 = no input
        Console.WriteLine(input.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now it handles every character separately.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: @Matthijs I misunderstood the question. I have now updated my answer.